# Retrieving items from a listbox with checkbox items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, listbox

I'm creating a WPF application. I have a listbox with checkbox items inside, and I need to be able to retrieve what the value of the checkboxes are (whether the user has checked them or not). Here is my MainWindow code.

```
    <ListBox Name="lbFacilities" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Height="85">
        <CheckBox>Hiking</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox>Swimming</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox>Skiing</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox>Camping</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox>Lodging</CheckBox>
    </ListBox>
```

How can I bring those checkbox items (Hiking, Swimming, etc.) into my C# code as bool datatypes?

UPDATE - I tried tsells "easy" method, thinking it would work for me, and it did not. Justin said that it worked for him though, so here's my code now.

```
<ListBox Name="lbFacilities" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Height="85">
        <CheckBox Name="chbHiking">Hiking</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Name="chbSwimming">Swimming</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Name="chbSkiing">Skiing</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Name="chbCamping">Camping</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Name="chbLodging">Lodging</CheckBox>
    </ListBox>
```

Then in my C# code

```
bool isHiking;
isHiking = chbHiking.IsChecked;
```

The second line assigning isHiking gives an error, saying chbHiking does not exist.

Comment: By the way, if you don't need item selection use an `ItemsControl`.

Comment: it should be chbHiking.IsChecked

Comment: I capitalized IsChecked and it still says that chbHiking does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Just as a test, what happens if you try to access lbFacilities in your code? If something is not being wired right, then this should give the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [data templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx), you will want to create a list of items which has a boolean property and a string to display, then bind the [`ListBox.ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) to that and create an [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) which creates the `CheckBoxes` binding the `IsChecked` and `Content` to your items.

Then you can just look at the property values in your source collection.

Comment: This is the way I would do it as well +1.  I missed the fact the checkboxes were inside a list box.  I saw a stack panel for some reason (mind playing tricks again).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't understand this much at all, but I'm going to try to look into it. I really thought there would be a simpler way like tsells suggested, but it seems like there isn't.

Comment: @user1241563: The most simple way is not necessarily the best, as there may be downsides in the long run. Doing it with bindings and data templates becomes simple in time when you get used to it, and it pays off.

Comment: I understand that, and appreciate the input. However, this is for an assignment for a class that I have only been in for about a month and a half. I am very new to C# programming and I do not feel that my professor would implement something so complex into this assignment, as we have not gone over it. I feel that there is a simpler way that I am overlooking.

Comment: @user1241563: A professor teaching WPF... what a crazy notion, from my perspective at least. Well, for an assignment you might as well fudge it, but WPF is all about data binding and templating, so sooner or later you should learn it if you want to work efficiently. What you posted in your question should work, where exactly did you place the c# code?

Comment: I currently have it placed in a button click method, as this assignment pertains to search criteria for State Parks. I have other inputs such as a DatePicker and a ComboBox that are being retrieved just in my C# code just fine.

Comment: @user1241563: Unless the XAML snippet is itself part of a resource or template you should be able to access the controls by name. Hard to tell what is wrong without the full code. Also... why are we helping you with *your* assignment, something is wrong here...

Comment: I know, I should be doing it myself. This part has completely tripped me up though, and I have no idea how to get past it. Here are copies of my XAML and C# code, respectively: http://slexy.org/view/s2Z4Z2NiE7 and http://slexy.org/view/s20PU2nAfi. I would appreciate any more help, but understand completely if you don't want to.

Comment: @user1241563: Looking over it i couldn't spot anything which could prevent it from working, but that is some horrible code-behind. This isn't C, you don't need to declare all local variables at the top, declare them where you need them.

Comment: Thank you for looking over it anyways, and thanks for the input. I'm just doing it the way our professor has demonstrated in class.

Comment: @user1241563: I really begin to question the quality of what you are being taught there :P

Comment: That may be why I am completely lost, and have gone to the internet for help at the eleventh hour. Thank you for all your help regardless. Hopefully I will figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1)  Easy

```
<CheckBox Name="cbHiking">Hiking</CheckBox>
```

In Code Behind

```
bool isHiking = cbHiking.IsChecked;
```

2) Harder - Data Binding

```
<CheckBox Name="cbHiking" IsChecked="{Binding Path=MyHiking}">Hiking</CheckBox>
```

In Code Behind (Normally a view model)

```
private bool _myhiking;
public bool MyHiking {get {return _myhiking;} set {_myhiking = value;   //DoPropertyCHanged}
```

Please note though I would not recommend doing it this way for production code. I missed the fact they were in the list box on first glance.    The best option would be to use a CheckedListBox and then bind that to a collection of objects that contained the description (name) and a value of whether or not they were selected.

Comment: Ah, I never even thought of giving them names! Thank you, I think that's the solution I'm looking for. Edit - Actually, that's not working for me. I'm getting an error that "cbHiking" doesn't exist in my code.

Comment: I just ran this myself and had no problems. Can you update your code?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you just want to know if they are checked or not. If so, then you can do this:

```
foreach (var item in lbFacilities.Items)
{
    CheckBox cb = item as CheckBox;
    bool thisCBCheckedValue = cb.IsChecked;
}
```